# Checkbox value is always returning false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox

```
<input id="Run" name="Run" value="true" type="checkbox">

<input name="Run" value="false" type="hidden">
```

and When I try to get the value it always returns false

```
 $('#Run').val()

"False"
```

I tried to get the value using .prop

```
$('#Run').prop('checked')
```

but I still get the value as false

I also tried

```
 $('#Run').on('change', function () {
        $('#Run').val($(this).is(':checked') ? 'True' : 'False');
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you only want to access checkbox property then try this one.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Run').on('change', function () {
           alert($(this).is(':checked'));
        });
    });
```

if you only want to access checkbox property and assign to hidden input then try this one.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Run').on('change', function () {
            $('input[name="Run"]').val($(this).is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks , Worked when I used name="Run"

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Run').on('change', function () {
     $('input[type=hidden]').val($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

[is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) will return either true or false

[DEMO Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Rino_Raj/4qwzpx52/6/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function checkCheckbox() {
    document.getElementById('RunHidden').value = document.getElementById('Run').checked;
}
```

```html
<input id="Run" name="Run" value="true" onchange="checkCheckbox()" type="checkbox">
<input id="RunHidden" name="RunHidden" value="false" type="text">
```

*Check if checkbox `Run` is checked:*

---

**Pure JavaScript**:

```
if(document.getElementById('Run').checked) {
    alert('Checked!');
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
if($("#Run").is(':checked')) {
    alert('Checked!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You always set checked=true for checkboxes instead of value=true.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="true"/>
```

to check it value you need to check as

```
var boolean = $('#idOfCheckbox').is(':checked');
```

It the attribute **checked** that is important
This is same in case of radiobuttons as well.

Value is used for textboxes(input type=text)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from various functions like `.is(':checked')`, `.prop('checked')`, `.attr('checked')`, you can try using the wild card selectors if your control is in update panel like

To get all the elements starting with "mock" you should use:

```
$("[id^=mock]")
```

To get those that end with "mock"

```
$("[id$=mock]")
```

See also the [**JQuery documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)